# Creating a document library with a custom template

Tags: document-library, document-template

What I want is basically a good solution for people to be able to fill out a form on the web and then save it in the online library.

You need to be able to automatically create a document from a template in just one or two clicks from the page and then automatically save it to the online-library.

When this is done, the admin of the site will get a notification (this i think i know how to fix thought) so he can examine the new document instantly.

How can this be done?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the description. You want a web form that saves entries? Is it to be saved in a Word file? Do you want the answers stored in columns?

Add some more detail...and I'll get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @jpollar. For some reason, a guy comes and edits my spelling and he also completely changed my title... Anyhow, i have managed to solove the problem on my own. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Soloved it using InfoPath. Gave me a even better result. Cheers.